# Problems getting Symfony to work locally with the `host: "web.{domain}"` setting

Tags: symfony

I am trying to get an old project (not made by me) up and running, and I see that the routes are configured [in some peculiar format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations). This is a typical route config:

```
customer_home:
    path: /customer
    host: "web.{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: "BackendBundle:Customer:index"
        domain: "%domain%"
    methods: [get]
    options:
        expose: true
   requirements:
       domain: '%domain%'
```

Now, I grepped the source code and found `domain` in the config files. It was `null` by default and by setting it to `localhost:8000` I was able to at least load the root without complaints about `%domain%`. Now it complains about not finding a matching route, which makes sense, as none was configured. What was configured (which I found by doing `console debug:router`) was a root route for `admin.{domain}` and `web.{domain}`. I assume this means that if the domain is myapp.com, there should be routes configured for `admin.myapp.com/` and `web.myapp.com`.

This is a local development setup, running on 127.0.0.1:8000, so I tried adding this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   web.localhost admin.localhost
```

I was now hoping that going to `web.localhost:8000` would load a route, but none was matched. I still get `NotFoundHttpException`, but now I no longer understand why ... How can I configure this setup so that I can load the `web` and `admin` subdomains on my development machine? Other routes, like `/api/1/doc`, works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to set the domain parameter to `localhost` only (without the port)?

Comment: The domain shouldn't include the port number. These are different things. And what version of Symfony is this? Can't find any version that Symfony that used "domain". It's usually `host`.

Comment: Version 3.1 of Symfony. PS. You are mixing up two different things. It's still using host.

Comment: @AlessandroChitolina It was as you said; drop the port number. I was not aware that the port 8000 setting was implicit/default, so I thought it needed to be set somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not far off. The answer was to simply drop the port portion of what I had entered as the `domain` setting. So  `domain: localhost` did the trick. The server is [by default running on port 8000](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/setup/built_in_web_server.html), no matter the setting, so it was not needed. I can now access `web.localhost` and `admin.localhost` (after adding them as host aliases for the loopback device in `/etc/hosts`).